# ERROR 1071 (42000) : Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've been trying to get this old .sql imported into:

```
Server version: 10.8.3-MariaDB
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)
InnoDB
```

and have read a ton of SO answers on this error, but it seems no matter how low I set the varchars, I just keep getting the same error. Originally it was:

```
CREATE TABLE nuke_cpg_pictures (
   pid int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
   aid int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   filepath varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   filename varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   filesize int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   total_filesize int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   pwidth smallint(6) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   pheight smallint(6) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   hits int(10) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   mtime timestamp(14),
   ctime int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   owner_id int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   owner_name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
   pic_rating int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   votes int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   caption text NOT NULL,
   keywords varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   approved enum('YES','NO') DEFAULT 'NO' NOT NULL,
   user1 varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   user2 varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   user3 varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   user4 varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   url_prefix tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   randpos int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   pic_raw_ip tinytext,
   pic_hdr_ip tinytext,
   PRIMARY KEY (pid),
   KEY pic_hits (hits),
   KEY pic_rate (pic_rating),
   KEY aid_approved (aid, approved),
   KEY randpos (randpos),
   KEY pic_aid (aid),
   KEY search (title, caption, keywords, filename)
);
```

and currently it's at:

```
CREATE TABLE nuke_cpg_pictures (
   pid int NOT NULL auto_increment,
   aid int DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   filepath varchar(80) NOT NULL,
   filename varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   filesize int DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   total_filesize int DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   pwidth smallint(6) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   pheight smallint(6) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   hits int DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   mtime timestamp(6),
   ctime int DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   owner_id int DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   owner_name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
   pic_rating int DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   votes int( DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   title varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   caption text NOT NULL,
   keywords varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   approved enum('YES','NO') DEFAULT 'NO' NOT NULL,
   user1 varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   user2 varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   user3 varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   user4 varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   url_prefix tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   randpos int DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   pic_raw_ip tinytext,
   pic_hdr_ip tinytext,
   PRIMARY KEY (pid),
   KEY pic_hits (hits),
   KEY pic_rate (pic_rating),
   KEY aid_approved (aid, approved),
   KEY randpos (randpos),
   KEY pic_aid (aid),
   KEY search (title, caption, keywords, filename)
);
```

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: You cannot index TEXT column. You **must** specify its prefix length to be indexed.

Comment: Read [TEXT datatype - Indexing](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/text/#indexing). TEXT datatype column without length specifying can be indexed only separately, and in this case the hash of the value is indexed really (i.e. this index is not applicable for searching).

Comment: There seems to be a lot of probably irrelevant code noise in your question. Can you please remove as many columns as possible yet the remaining code still shows the error, ie create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Akina this is a db from 2004 (not mine) and it was simply exported this way. What would you suggest to be the best solution in this case? Change to `KEY search (title, keywords, filename)`? (remove the caption column from the search key)?

Comment: It would seem a little odd that someone would search the index `search` ready knowing the `caption` value so I think that would be a good move.

Comment: Do you really think that the structure of one table is enough to give meaningful advice?

Comment: @Akina Well, I'm already getting yelled at about "too much code noise" by a mod, ;) so, I don't want to just dump a bunch of code, especially when I'm not 100% sure where the issue lies to begin with.

Comment: The index serves some process, probably this is searching. You must at least describe your searching patterns and show according queries marking the most critical ones. Of course we need data statistic (separate and total matched rows amounts).

Comment: may be helpful  https://youtu.be/EWZfHyNs08c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No column declared `TEXT` can be indexed.  It seems unlikely that you would benefit from

```
INDEX (title, caption, keywords, filename)
```

Whereas you might benefit from

```
FULLTEXT (title, caption, keywords, filename)
```

But that would mean using this for searching:

```
WHERE MATCH (title, caption, keywords, filename)
         AGAINST ("...")
```

See the documentation for what things you can put in the `AGAINST` clause.  `FULLTEXT` is very good for searching for "words" in one or more (4 in your case) columns.  `FULLTEXT` is happy to handle `TEXT` column(s); `INDEX` (aka `KEY`) is not.

As for the suggestion of using a 'prefix' (eg, `caption(100)`), you will probably find that it is either useless or counterproductive.

As for changing to `INDEX(title, keywords, filename)`, please show us the query that might want to use that index.  It *may not* be applicable.

If `caption` is never very long, then change to a `VARCHAR` with a suitable maximum.  Ditto for the other strings.

If you are using `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`, you will not be able to have 4 `VARCHAR(255)` in a single `INDEX` -- it will hit the 3072 limit.  Either shrink the sizes, change the charset, or (probably best), switch to FULLTEXT.

Please provide some kind of sample `SELECT`.

Other notes:

`pic_raw_ip tinytext` -- Is that an IP address?  `VARCHAR(39)` is more appropriate; `TINYTEXT` is almost always ill-advised.

`url_prefix` sounds like a string, but it is declared `tinyint(4)` which has a range -128 ti +127.  What gives?

`filesize int` -- Be aware that that is limited to 2GB; probably OK for pictures (this decade), but not for videos.

Comment: Very helpful info, Rick. Appreciate it very much. Regarding the last 3 questions, your guess is as good as mine at this point in time, lol. You'd have to ask the author of the Coppermine gallery why he chose those, right now I'm just trying to get the db to restore  at all, before I look into (possibly) fixing up any previous author's mistakes. =)

Comment: Also, this is a db from a semi-private (just amongst friends) PHPNuke CMS site w/Coppermine gallery as an addon module, from 2004, so the filesize int makes a bit more sense in that context.

Comment: @J.ScottElblein - They are common "novice" issues; they mostly just work.  2004 -- OK, I think two things conspired to 'cause' the 3072 problem -- The default engine changed from MyISAM (with a limit of 1000 for indexes) and the default character set changed from latin1 (1 byte per character) to utf8mb4 (up to 4 bytes per character).  Hence...

Comment: @J.ScottElblein - you will have to make at least _some of_ the changes to get the table working.  (Yes, I was actively using MySQL even before 2004, so I have watched the changes unfold over the years.)

Comment: I was as well (just gave away our age, lol) but more of a "dabbler" where I only learn just as much as I need to know to get something done. You're definitely my new "Buddish Monk meditating at the top of the mountain" MySQL guru from now on, :p

Comment: I've got another, probably simple, one for ya, if interested Rick. https://stackoverflow.com/q/72960418/553663

Comment: @J.ScottElblein - Another hint of my age:  I could read the holes "punched cards" encoding in BCD or EBCDIC.

Comment: lol, you may have me beat. a hint of mine; I was around 10-ish while playing all the new Atari 2600/Intellivison/ColecoVision/etc. game consoles in stores like Kmart. During the height of the Arcade/mall/PacMan/Donkey Kong era. lmao

Comment: "If you are using CHARACTER SET utf8mb4, you will not be able to have 4 VARCHAR(255) in a single INDEX -- it will hit the 3072 limit." was exactly my case, found it by removing a component at a time. Actually I had 3xVARCHAR(255) + 1xVARCHAR(45) and an integer, and it failed.

Answer (score 0):

in my case it worked to make the index as follows:

CREATE INDEX user_meta_key USING BTREE ON
db.user_postmeta (meta_key(255),meta_value(255));

as you can see I put the values in brackets to limit the value of the field to 255 and I did not use the longtext that I had as data type.
I hope this solution can help you, it worked for me.

Note: my engine is MariaDB